# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I already went through the documentation. I did login and register pages by using auth artisan command.

I am trying to store the values from the registration page but when I click on the submit button I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users`
> where `email` = xxxxxx@gmail.com)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the error message says it all: you supplied an incorrect MySQL username or password.

Answer (score 1):

Open the directory where you have installed the laravel.
Find the ".env" file and edit the database details there.

Or you can even setup them in the config/database.php file.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'glob_hire.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = bharathi@gmail.com)

Comment: because the users table is not there. you need to run the migration from the command prompt using the artisan command:  **php artisan migrate**

Comment: what value you have given into the DB_HOST variable?

Comment: if it is 127.0.0.1 then change it to localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138315/discussion-between-sahil-and-bharathi).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when we forget the configuration database file in the `.env` file:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from users
>   where email = xxxxxx@gmail.com)

**Solution:** Just need a correct configuration in the `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead 
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Don't forget to clear cache after changes:

```
php artisan config:cache
```